# how get data json in php

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm not getting any information from Json as I try
I want to get every single information and save it in the database

```
    {
"data":[
{
"name":"چلوکباب چنجه",
"price":"20000",
"phone":"0930",
"number":"2",
"orider_id":"1",
"img_name":"Changea.jpg"
},
{
"name":"سالاد فصل",
"price":"3000",
"phone":"0930",
"number":"2",
"orider_id":"1",
"img_name":"SaladFasl.jpg"
},
{
"name":"ایستک لیمو ",
"price":"2000",
"phone":"0930",
"number":"2",
"orider_id":"1",
"img_name":"Istak.jpeg"
}
]
}`
```

Comment: which way you get ?

Comment: `json_decode()` Its documented in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: `Im not getting any information from Json` It looks like you are though?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

use `json_decode` and get data as array, loop the data and you get each value

```
<?php
$data =  '{
"data":[
{
"name":"چلوکباب چنجه",
"price":"20000",
"phone":"0930",
"number":"2",
"orider_id":"1",
"img_name":"Changea.jpg"
},
{
"name":"سالاد فصل",
"price":"3000",
"phone":"0930",
"number":"2",
"orider_id":"1",
"img_name":"SaladFasl.jpg"
},
{
"name":"ایستک لیمو ",
"price":"2000",
"phone":"0930",
"number":"2",
"orider_id":"1",
"img_name":"Istak.jpeg"
}
]
}';
$data = json_decode($data);
foreach($data as $k=>$v){
    echo "<pre>";print_r($v);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please give me more guidance
How can I get one by one
Name and price, and ... get a string

Comment: Json can try me